# Unable to select rows in dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

**Background Information:**

I have two HTML tables.  Table "selected_users" represents records the user has selected, and "users" is a list of available users. "Users" is a jquery dataTable.

When the end user clicks on a record from "users", a few things need to happen:

1. Highlight the row that was just selected in the dataTable "users".
2. Copy the row data to "selected_users"
3. Search for any other row in "users" that has a matching "pnumber".
4. For all matching rows, copy the row data to "selected_users".
5. Highlight these matching rows in the dataTable.

**What's Not Working**

Everything except for step 5 is working.  The additional rows that have the matching pnumber are not being highlighted in the dataTable.  If you check out the code you'll see that I test the length of the "selected[]" js array to ensure that the size increases... and it does.
Its just on the GUI, the row is not highlighted.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected = [];


$('#users tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
var id = this.id;
var tr;
tr=$('<tr/>');

var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
if ( index === -1 ) {
    selected.push( id ); //select/highlight in list of available users.
    // Find td's inside this tr and add to selected_users table
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
    tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(0).text() + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(1).text() + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(2).text() + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(3).text() + "</td>");
    tr.attr('id', id.substring(4));
    $('#selected_users').append(tr);

    //test start - find and add all other rows with matching pnumber
    var thisTR = $(this);
    thisTR.siblings().filter(function() {
    if ($('td',this).eq(2).text() == $('td', thisTR).eq(2).text() ) {
        add_to_selected_users($(this));
        if (($.inArray(temp, selected)) === -1) {
                alert('need to highlight:' + this.id);
                selected.push(this.id);
                alert(selected.length);
        };
    };
    //test stop
});

} else {
        selected.splice( index, 1 ); //deselect from list of avail users
        //remove matching record from selected_users table.
        var record_id = id.substring(4);
        var rowtodelete = document.getElementById(record_id);
        rowtodelete.parentNode.removeChild(rowtodelete);
}
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
 } ); //end function
 } ); //end document ready
```

I'm sure it's something simple I've missed. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't throw the term "bug" about. This is most likely a bug in your code and not a bug in any JavaScript engine.

Comment: that's what i was referring to... bug in my code.  I will edit to clarify.

Comment: DataTables has its own methods to add rows and respond to events, probably you should use these methods instead of manipulating directly it's raw html.

Comment: @Mir, I will take another look at their sample code, but the original code I used, including the declaration and use of selected[] was from a code snippet on their site. the difference is that instead of requiring that a record be clicked on before selecting it, i'm trying to auto select a few rows...

Answer (score 0):

I changed this:

```
    if (($.inArray(temp, selected)) === -1) {
            alert('need to highlight:' + this.id);
            selected.push(this.id);
            alert(selected.length);
    };
```

to this:

```
          if (($.inArray(this.id, selected)) === -1) {
                    selected.push(this.id);
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            };
```